# Best practice for storing credit balance in web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, database-design

I am creating a web application where users can buy credits (using real money) and spend them on things.

I will need to keep a history of every time a user buys or spends credits.

I will often need to know the user's current credit balance.

I usually work to the principle that storing the same data twice is bad practice i.e. since I have a history of all increases and decreases in credit balance, I should not store the balance itself as a seperate field.

However, it seems overkill to calculate this balance each time the user opens up a new page (which will display their current balance). On the other hand, it seems wrong to store it either in the database, or in memory on the webserver, just to prevent the system having to work it out each time.

Does anyone have any experience of this and / or know what the recommended best practices are for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked on several projects with similar requirements, and there's nothing wrong with calculating the current balance on the fly - it's the least error prone solution, and this kind of query is what most databases are designed to do; unless you're working on a site with Facebook-levels of traffic, something like `"select sum(transactionValue) from transactions where userID = ?"` should be blazingly fast.

Storing the balance somewhere else - duplicating it, in effect - risks introducing subtle bugs and discrepancies, with the "cache" value getting out of sync with the underlying transactions; the amount of work required to get this right is probably significant.

Answer (score 2):

[Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) has its place. For example a table with forum topics also has a `PostCount` column, opposed to doing a `COUNT(posts)` for every topic. If you are worried about consistency, and you should, you can schedule regular checks (for example on each transaction from or to a given user) where you test if each user's `Balance` matches the sum of their transactions.

Comment: Yes the problem is though what to do when the check finds that Postcount != COUNT(Posts).

Comment: @GGG of course the the actual posts table (or your transaction log) is leading in case of a discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

Do not calculate the credit balance of every request.
The credit balance of each user is something that you should maintain.

Keep it in your database.
That way you don't have to worry about concurrency.
Use transactions to increment of decrement this value as the user uses your application.
Databases do optimize for recurring selects, so again, let your db take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Does calculating of the balance take time?  if not, just calculate in real-time with SQL.

But I'm foreseeing problems in the future when your log of transactions has grown bigger and bigger(millions of rows). When the select query from the transaction log will take time, then it's time to cache and pre calculate the balance and store it in your db.